# When implementing search in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement search in angularjs.

The number of records are `{{array.length}}`

when I filter the records with some (sample) text, it will display same(total) number of records, but not filtered number of records.

I need exact filtered number of records.

How can I achieve this?.

[Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/90unJ9JCGBPCSytwkqYt?p=preview).

Comment: Please post code.. or Fiddle of your working code..

Answer (score 3):

You can do;

```
ng-repeat="friendObj in filteredFriends = (friends | filter:search:strict)"
```

and ofcourse now,

```
{{filteredFriends.length}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little example...

```
<p>Number of visible items: {{(items|filter:search).length}}</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VJx6X/